# Unexpected margin with font-awesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a <ul> with `list-style-type:none;`. Instead of the list-icon I want to show a custom icon which should be variable *and* clickable. To make sure the custom icon appears to the left of the text's left margin, I added `text-indent:-17px;` and this works as expected.

However, when I have font-awesome icons in my text they seem to have their left margin (or, more like, their `text-indent`) set to the indent of the containing <div>. In the snapshot below the first <li> has a `text-indent:-17px`, the second `0px`, and the third `+20px`.

[image]

The first one clearly shows a negative `margin-left`/`text-indent` for the icon, while the last one has a positive margin-left.

How can I fix this, so that I can work with the negative indent?

The problem shows in FireFox v29, IE v11 and Chrome v35.
Font-Awesome is v4.1.0

---

My code:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li>
      <div style="text-indent:-17px; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <img src="http://i.stevenvh.net/tam_none.png" alt="" /> 
        Lorem <a href="#">ipsum  <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="text-indent:0px; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <img src="http://i.stevenvh.net/tam_none.png" alt="" /> 
        Lorem <a href="#">ipsum  <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="text-indent:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <img src="http://i.stevenvh.net/tam_none.png" alt="" /> 
        Lorem <a href="#">ipsum  <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i am not able to understand your expected output... can you share a screenshot for expected output as well?

Comment: @Aamir - The space between the word "ipsum" and the icon following it should be as in the second item.

Comment: Got it... CSS is missing for <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> in the provided HTML

Comment: @Aamir - Font-Awesome works with an external CSS library, which is way too long to include here. BTW, AFAIK there's no CSS which should behave like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `text-indent` is inherited. Setting that to 20px on the third item is adding it to the inner `i`

Doing something like this would reset the text-indent. Note the added style on the `i`

http://jsfiddle.net/dJqUh/2/

```
<li>
  <div style="text-indent:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <img src="http://i.stevenvh.net/tam_none.png" alt="" /> 
    Lorem <a href="#">ipsum  <i class="fa fa-external-link" style="text-indent:0px;"></i></a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
</li>
```

It didn't do anything wrong for the second item because you set the indent to 0. It overlapps the text in the first because you have a negative indent.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/83sg7/1/)**

```
a
{
    text-indent: 0; // inherited CSS - override it to fix the issue
}
```

Comment: Actually, the text-indent should be applied to the i tag, not the a tag. See *niko*'s answer. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: probably that is the right way to do - perhaps it solves the issue this way too...